# AWS API Gateway for interprocess communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I'm learning about microservice architecture and putting together some proof of concepts but I've hit a wall.

I've made a user service which serverless which is hosted on amazon AWS using Lambda with a public API Gateway which allows you to query the user database. It's pretty simple and just looks something like:

```
api/users?email=myemail@gmail.com
```

This API has authorization associated with it because some users are allowed to know about other users and some are not. So for some users this would return 404 (or 403 perhaps) and for others they would get 200 and the result.

Now I come to write the authentication service which takes an email address and password and returns a token. How should I approach getting the user data from the user service? I'd love to just call the REST API but it has authorization on it because it's public. Also, the public API wouldn't return the (hashed) password field which I would need.

So my question:

**Should I have a separate, private API for inter-service communication which returns all the information or should I have a magic authorization key that I send to the api which identifies the requester as an internal service and so to show everything.**

Supplementary question:

**If I do use the public API with a magic auth code, should I just be calling fetch using the same public api url that my client side service would use or should I call some internal amazon url?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question has one good answer. But here are some thoughts:

1. Are you sure you need individual auth and user services and can't build it as one unit? This would be more efficient — in general people try to avoid calling lambda functions from lambda functions because it's slower and can be hard to test/debug.
2. If you need to communicate between lambdas you can invoke one directly rather than going through the api gateway using the SDK of the language you're using. For example javascript: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property This way you can control access with roles and policies.
3. Don't reinvent the wheel. Have you looked at AWS Cognito? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html